# Moving from ActionBarSherlock to AppCompat now getting a WindowDecor Error

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15100): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(15100):    at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.getDecorToolbar(WindowDecorActionBar.java:248)
E/AndroidRuntime(15100):    at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.init(WindowDecorActionBar.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(15100):    at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.<init>(WindowDecorActionBar.java:176)
E/AndroidRuntime(15100):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.createSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:156)
E/AndroidRuntime(15100):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(15100):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onTitleChanged(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:462)
E/AndroidRuntime(15100):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onTitleChanged(ActionBarActivity.java:176)
E/AndroidRuntime(15100):    at android.app.Activity.onPostCreate(Activity.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime(15100):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
E/AndroidRuntime(15100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2188)
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this or has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Are you using AppCompat v21? If so, follow this guide to properly change your app for it: http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/ [If this IS due to AppCompatv21, then the error probably lies in the Theme not being set up correctly]

Comment: I got this error when I had `setContentView` before calling `super.onCreate`. When I switched the order of operations around, the error went away. Can you double check whether you have the same issue?

Comment: @SunnySydeUp I think this is the problem. I have two base activities for a err activity and I think this is causing the problem